# Delete Firebase Node with OnClick Function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two JavaScript functions, one to generate a table and the other to delete a row by removing the node from the Firebase database. I keep getting an error that says deleteRecord() function is undefined. Please assist...

```
            function generate_table(){

                        $('#emp_body').html('');    
                        console.log(dArr);

                        for (var i = 0; i < dArr.length; i++) {

                        var tr;
                        tr = $('<tr/>');

                        var strSleeve = "View Sleeve";
                        var sleeveLink = strSleeve.link(dArr[i][1].downloadURLSleeve);
                        var strAud = "View Audio";
                        var audioLink = strAud.link(dArr[i][1].downloadURLFile);
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  (i+1) + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  childKeys[i] + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].stageName + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].fullName + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].email + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].city + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].cell + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  sleeveLink + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  audioLink + "</td>");


                                    tr.append('<td>' + '<button id="deleteBtn" onclick="deleteRecord(\''+childKeys[i]+'\');" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Record</button>' + '</td>');
                                    $('#emp_body').append(tr);

                }

            }


                                        // DELETE FUNCTION
            function deleteRecord(key){     
                                var refDB = firebase.database().ref().child('submissions/'+key);
                                    refDB.once("value")
                                    .then(function(snapshot) {
                                        snapshot.ref.remove();
                                        alert("Record deleted..!");
                                }).catch(function(error) {alert("Data could not be deleted." + error);});
                        }
```

Comment: You haven't shown any onClick handlers, or the line of code that calls deleteRecord.

Comment: Thank you... that actually got me somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You should do as follows:

```
        function deleteRecord(key){     
                            var refDB = firebase.database().ref('submissions/' + key);
                            refDB.remove()
                            .then(function() {
                              console.log("Remove succeeded.")
                            })
                            .catch(function(error) {
                              console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
                            });
                    }
```

See the corresponding doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#remove

You should not use the `once()` method which is used to read data, as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. I think things will get easier from here. For now I am going to use the url to the specific node and delete the item from firebase while I try to figure out a better approach.

```
            function generate_table(){

                        $('#emp_body').html('');    
                        console.log(dArr);

                        for (var i = 0; i < dArr.length; i++) {

                        var tr;
                        tr = $('<tr/>');

                        var strSleeve = "View Sleeve";
                        var sleeveLink = strSleeve.link(dArr[i][1].downloadURLSleeve);
                        var strAud = "View Audio";
                        var audioLink = strAud.link(dArr[i][1].downloadURLFile);
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  (i+1) + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  childKeys[i] + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].stageName + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].fullName + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].email + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].city + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  dArr[i][1].cell + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  sleeveLink + "</td>");
                                    tr.append("<td>" +  audioLink + "</td>");

                                    var deleteLink = 'https://myFirebaseAuthDomain.firebaseio.com/submissions'+'/'+ childKeys[i];

                                  tr.append('<td>' + '<button id="deleteBtn"  class="btn btn-danger">Delete Record</button>' + '</td>');
                                    $('#emp_body').append(tr);

                                    document.getElementById("deleteBtn").onclick = function() 
                                                {
                                                        console.log("AHOY!" + deleteLink);
                                                        var win = window.open(deleteLink, '_blank');
                                                        win.focus();
                                                };

                    }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you fetch the data for the table and at that point Firebase is out of the picture. You take the response data and use JavaScript or whateverScript to build out your UI as you like, in your case you want a table.

I recommend that you add a `dataset` property to each table row which hold the value of whatever node that row represents, e.g. `dataset.myid = a8hKE21Nswtevr` applied to each `<tr>`.

You then appy a click listener to the entire table, or to the rows (by class), and all you have to do is `evt.target.parentElement.dataset.myid` to get the specific thing the end user clicked.

You then take that uid and talk to firebase as needed.